# multiple filter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am new to angular. I have a json object:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name1",
    "speciality": "speciality1",
    "address": "address1",
    "phoneNumber": 9999999999
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "name2",
    "speciality": "speciality2",
    "address": "address2",
    "phoneNumber": 9999999999
  },
...
]
```

and I want to filter based on two properties: `name` and `speciality`. This search is matching insensitive substring. How to do this? The way I am doing this is as follows, which doesn't work:

```
$filter('filter')(doctor.details, { $: query }, false, [name, speciality]);
$filter('filter')(doctor.details, { name: query } || {speciality : query }, false);
```

`doctor.details` is the json object array, query is the (sub)string to be matched with `name` or `speciality`.

Comment: Does user enter `query` in a text box?

Comment: @RaviTeja no, i don't. can you help me doing it in the 'angular way'?

Comment: then how? Is it just a variable on scope?

Comment: @RaviTeja I am following https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it using `lodash` as this was the easiest I could think of:

```
_.union($filter('filter')(doctor.details, { name: query }), $filter('filter')(doctor.details, { speciality: query }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a AngularJS `filter` to filter out the list based on `query` matching `name` and `speciality` properties.

```
app.filter('filterDetails', function() {
  return function(details, query) {

    var filteredDetails = [];
    filteredDetails = details.filter(function(obj) {
      // look whether query is substring of name or speciality
      if (~obj.name.indexOf(query) || ~obj.speciality.indexOf(query)) {
        return obj;
      }
    })
    // finally return filtered array
    return filteredDetails;
  };
});
```

HTML

```
 Query :
  <input type="text" ng-model="query" />

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="detail in doctor.details | filterDetails:query">
      {{ detail }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/RsgrQexN18z7ydtNRzM4?p=preview)